# example of best practice to refer to when getting started with NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I would like to have a simple sample NH project that you would consider best practice that people could refer to when getting started with NH?

I've been using it for a couple of months now and still struggle with the numerous ways there are to do things but not knowing which is the best approach to follow.

Comment: There's no such thing as best approach. There are many valid approaches and the one you should pick will very largely depend on your scenario. So I would suggest you start by describing your scenario. Remember that the more details you provide the more answers will be getting closer to this *elusive best approach* you are talking about. Another approach which I think is good would be to pick an approach, try it, develop some sample application, see if it works for your scenario and share the code here so that we can discuss and improve it if necessary.

Comment: How can I keep logical tiers loosely coupled, at the same time have a Test driven approach, Onions teschniques...etc?

Comment: Why do we always need to wrap a transaction in a using statement?

Comment: Using statement: disposing the object, closing the transaction, flushing the session.

Comment: About the Onion Architecture, see my answer here below. Codecampserver is written by Jeffrey Palermo, who AFAIK invented the term. And, very practical, a (free manuscript) book goes with the project: see http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/read-all-of-asp-net-mvc-2-in-action-now-while-you-wait-for-the-printed-book/

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the best samples is [sharp architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/default.aspx). You can find Northwind example there.

Also you can look at Best practices on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[uNhAddIns](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/) also contains some excellent samples.

[Effectus](http://github.com/ayende/effectus) is also interesting.

Still, I'll have to agree with Darin Dimitrov. There's no such things as "best" practices; there are many ways to do things and each one has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I learned quite a bit from the [WhoCanHelpMe](http://github.com/jongeorge1/Who-Can-Help-Me) application, which provides a nice reference implementation of the [S#arp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/default.aspx) framework.

In addition to this, a wealth of information can be found on the following blogs which belong to NHibernate contributors:

- [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/default.aspx)
- [Fabio Maulo](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/)
- [Davy Brion](http://davybrion.com/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that really depends on what you mean by best approach. You may like watching some dimecasts screencasts on the subject, I have found them very informative. There are also loads of other topics too. [Dimecasts.net](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/NHibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Code Camp Server is a nice reference for ASP.NET MVC and NHibernate
http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/

Also, read a book on the subjects. It will help you a long way.

Edit:
You seem to be looking for a general guide, to take you through some concepts of good design etc. Specifically for ASP.NET MVC, I can recommend http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/read-all-of-asp-net-mvc-2-in-action-now-while-you-wait-for-the-printed-book/

You mention Onion architecture, the book was written by Jeffrey Palermo, who (AFAIK) invented the term.

If you'd like more sample projects (there are lots and lots) of ASP.NET MVC (with or without NH), let me know.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/ is a great screencast series on NHibernate